# Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Tags: codeigniter

Iam stuck with this problem (searching and testing still failed).
I using codeigniter (newbie). I dont know where the problem coz this error not showing.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string
Filename: controllers/bpjs_kesehatan.php
Line Number: 627


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\csi\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 442

A Database Error Occurred
The query you submitted is not valid.
Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\csi\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 257
```

**my controller**

```
function laporan_form34()
    {
        $bagianWhere = "";

        if (isset($_POST['check_nik']))
        {
           $nik = $this->input->post('nik');
           if (empty($bagianWhere))
           {
                $bagianWhere .= "bk.nik like '%$nik%'";
           }
        }



        if (isset($_POST['check_npp']))
        {
           $npp = $this->input->post('npp');
           if (empty($bagianWhere))
           {
                $bagianWhere .= "b.npp = '$npp'";
           }
           else
           {
                $bagianWhere .= " AND b.npp = '$npp'";
           }
        }


        if (isset($_POST['check_kk']))
        {
           $kk = $this->input->post('kk');
           if (empty($bagianWhere))
           {
                $bagianWhere .= "bk.no_kk like '%$kk%'";
           }
           else
           {
                $bagianWhere .= "AND bk.no_kk like '%$kk%'";
           }
        }

        if (empty($bagianWhere))
        {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_messages', 'ERROR : Minimal salah satu kriteria harus diisi !');
           redirect( base_url() . 'bpjs_kesehatan/form34');
        }
        else
        {
            $result_criteria = $this->app_model->manualQuery("select b.nik,b.hubkel
            from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b
            on b.nik = bk.nik where bk.status_karyawan = 'Aktif' and " . $bagianWhere ." order by b.nik");
        }

        //show data to view
        $bc['dt_karyawan'] = $this->db->query("$result_criteria");  
        $this->load->view('bpjs_kesehatan/laporan_form34',$bc);

    }
```

**My View**

```
foreach($dt_karyawan->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $hubkel = $row['hubkel'];
            $nik = $row['nik'];

            if($hubkel=='pegawai')
            {
                //HUBKEL PEGAWAI
                $query_pegawai = "select bk.no_kk as 'no_2',bk.nik as 'no_3',bk.nama as 'no_4',
                '1' as 'no_5',bk.tempat_lahir as 'no_6',bk.tgl_lahir as 'no_7',bk.jenis_kelamin as 'no_8','1' as 'no_9',
                bk.nama_ibu as 'no_10',bk.alamat as 'no_11',bk.rt as 'no_12',bk.rw as 'no_13',bk.kodepos as 'no_14',
                bk.kode_kecamatan as 'no_15',bk.nama_kecamatan as 'no_16',
                bk.kode_desa as 'no_17',bk.nama_desa as 'no_18',b.kode_faskes as 'no_19',b.nama_faskes as 'no_20',
                b.kode_faskes_gigi as 'no_21',b.nama_faskes_gigi as 'no_22',bk.no_hp as 'no_23',
                bk.email as 'no_24',b.npp as 'no_25','security' as 'no_26','2' as 'no_27',b.kelas_rawat as 'no_28',
                bk.tgl_masuk as 'no_29',
                '-' as 'no_30',bk.kewarganegaraan as 'no_31',b.asuransilainnya_nopolis as 'no_32',
                b.asuransilainnya_namaasuransi as 'no_33',b.no_npwp as 'no_34',b.no_passport as 'no_35'
                from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b on bk.nik=b.nik where b.nik='$nik'";
            }

            if($hubkel=='istri')
            {
                //HUBKEL ISTRI
                $query_istri = "select bk.no_kk_pasangan as 'no_2',bk.nik as 'no_3',bk.sp_nama_ibu as 'no_4',
                '3' as 'no_5',bk.sp_tmptlhr_ibu as 'no_6',bk.sp_tgllhr_ibu as 'no_7','2' as 'no_8','2' as 'no_9',
                bk.sp_namaibukandung_ibu as 'no_10',bk.alamat_pasangan as 'no_11',bk.rt_pasangan as 'no_12',
                bk.rw_pasangan as 'no_13',bk.kodepos_pasangan as 'no_14',
                bk.kode_kecamatan_pasangan as 'no_15',bk.nama_kecamatan_pasangan as 'no_16',
                bk.kode_desa_pasangan as 'no_17',bk.nama_desa_pasangan as 'no_18',b.kode_faskes as 'no_19',
                b.nama_faskes as 'no_20',
                b.kode_faskes_gigi as 'no_21',b.nama_faskes_gigi as 'no_22','-' as 'no_23',
                '-' as 'no_24',b.npp as 'no_25','-' as 'no_26','-' as 'no_27',b.kelas_rawat as 'no_28','-' as 'no_29',
                '-' as 'no_30',bk.kewarganegaraan as 'no_31',b.asuransilainnya_nopolis as 'no_32',
                b.asuransilainnya_namaasuransi as 'no_33',b.no_npwp as 'no_34',b.no_passport as 'no_35'
                from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b on bk.nik=b.nik where b.nik='$nik'";
            }

            if($hubkel=='suami')
            {
                //HUBKEL SUAMI
                $query_suami = "select bk.no_kk_pasangan as 'no_2',bk.nik as 'no_3',bk.sp_nama_ayah as 'no_4',
                '2' as 'no_5',bk.sp_tmptlhr_ayah as 'no_6',bk.sp_tgllhr_ayah as 'no_7','3' as 'no_8','2' as 'no_9',
                bk.sp_namaayahkandung_ibu as 'no_10',bk.alamat_pasangan as 'no_11',bk.rt_pasangan as 'no_12',
                bk.rw_pasangan as 'no_13',bk.kodepos_pasangan as 'no_14',
                bk.kode_kecamatan_pasangan as 'no_15',bk.nama_kecamatan_pasangan as 'no_16',
                bk.kode_desa_pasangan as 'no_17',bk.nama_desa_pasangan as 'no_18',b.kode_faskes as 'no_19',
                b.nama_faskes as 'no_20',
                b.kode_faskes_gigi as 'no_21',b.nama_faskes_gigi as 'no_22','-' as 'no_23',
                '-' as 'no_24',b.npp as 'no_25','-' as 'no_26','-' as 'no_27',b.kelas_rawat as 'no_28','-' as 'no_29',
                '-' as 'no_30',bk.kewarganegaraan as 'no_31',b.asuransilainnya_nopolis as 'no_32',
                b.asuransilainnya_namaasuransi as 'no_33',b.no_npwp as 'no_34',b.no_passport as 'no_35'
                from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b on bk.nik=b.nik where b.nik='$nik'";
            }
            if(!empty($query_pegawai))
        {

            foreach($query_pegawai->result() as $data)
            {
                echo '<tr align="center">';                                
                echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_2.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_3.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_4.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_5.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_6.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_7.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_8.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_9.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_10.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_11.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_12.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_13.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_14.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_15.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_16.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_17.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_18.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_19.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_20.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_21.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_22.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_23.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_24.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_25.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_26.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_27.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_28.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_29.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_30.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_31.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_32.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$data->no_33.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_34.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_35.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';   

            }
        }

    if(!empty($query_istri))
    {

        foreach($query_istri->result() as $data)
        {
            echo '<tr align="center">';                                
            echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_2.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_3.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_4.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_5.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_6.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_7.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_8.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_9.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_10.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_11.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_12.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_13.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_14.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_15.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_16.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_17.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_18.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_19.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_20.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_21.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_22.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_23.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_24.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_25.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_26.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_27.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_28.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_29.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_30.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_31.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_32.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$data->no_33.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_34.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data->no_35.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';   

        }
    }
```

}

the $dt_karyawan have many records. but I must selected data base on hubkel = (pegawai,suami,istri) using query again.
where my problem guys? 
thanks to your time.

Comment: The query that you are building is either with a sintax error, or so ething is not matching your schema. Can you get an output of the built query that you intend to run?

Comment: thanks @Alariva for your time before. I cant get output if using manual query..

Comment: this question solve at this link guys : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601387/codeigniter-foreach-array-in-foreach