# codeigniter foreach (array) in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I am nubie in Codeigniter. to the point. I have query in my controller

**My Controller**

```
$result_criteria = $this->app_model->manualQuery("select b.nik,b.hubkel
from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b
on b.nik = bk.nik where bk.status_karyawan = 'Aktif' and " . $bagianWhere ." order by b.nik");

$bc['dt_karyawan'] = $this->db->query("$result_criteria");
```

then it's my view where my foreach in foreach because I want selected by category of **b.hubkel** like this

**My View**

```
foreach($dt_karyawan->result() as $row)
{
  if($row->hubkel=='pegawai')
  {
    $query_pegawai = "select bk.no_kk as 'no_2' ....";
    foreach($query_pegawai->result() as $data1)
    {
        echo '<tr align="center">';                                
        echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data1->no_2.'</td>';
        .
        .
    }
  }
  if($row->hubkel=='istri')
  { 
    .
    .
    .
  }
 }
```

what wrong with my code guy? I have searching but not understand with this.
thanks for your time

Comment: I would investigate the magic of print_r, var_export, or var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in controller

```
     $result_criteria = $this->app_model->manualQuery("select b.nik,b.hubkel
      from biodata_karyawan bk left join bpjs b
     on b.nik = bk.nik where bk.status_karyawan = 'Aktif' and " .        $bagianWhere ." order by b.nik");

     $bc['dt_karyawan'] = $this->db->query($result_criteria)->result();
```

change in views as following

```
  foreach($dt_karyawan as $row)
 {
 if($row->hubkel=='pegawai')
 {
  $query_pegawai = "select bk.no_kk as 'no_2' ....";
   foreach($query_pegawai->result() as $data1)
   {
    echo '<tr align="center">';                                
    echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$kutip.$data1->no_2.'</td>';
    .
    .
    }
  }
 if($row->hubkel=='istri')
 { 
 .
 .
 .
 }
 }
```